# Java 8 enhanced for loop with index/range

Tags: java, java-8, apache-commons

Is it possible to specify an index/range in enhanced for loop in Java?

For e.g. I have a list: `List<String> list;`

And I want to run a for loop from index 1 instead of 0:

```
for(String s : list(start from index 1))
```

OR till index 5

```
for(String s : list(end at index 5))
```

I know I can use traditional for loop or keep a counter inside the enhanced for loop but I wanted to know is there something out of the box in Java or apache collections?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) in this case:

```
for(String s : list.subList(1, list.size()))
```

and

```
for(String s : list.subList(0, 6))
```

Answer (score 11):

Using of `sublist` is better but stream version is using `skip` and `limit`:

```
list.stream().skip(1) .... limit(6).....
```

Answer (score 6):

In the Java 8 we have Stream API, which we could use to iterate over List with custom indexes:

```
List<String> evenIndexes = IntStream
  .range(0, names.length)
  .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
  .mapToObj(i -> names[i])
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

in the `range` method, you could start from 1, and/or iterate to 5.

Answer (score 5):

The traditional for loop is the "out of the box" solution for this requirement:

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String s = list.get(i);
    ...
}
```

and (if the `List` has at least 5 elements):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String s = list.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of the performance penalty, but you can use `List::subList`

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

for (String s : list.subList(1, list.size())) {
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

**output**

```
2
3
```

Comment: You don’t need `new String []`; you can simply write `Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")`. Since `subList` doesn’t copy elements, the performance penalty is negligible, if any.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `list.subList(1, list.size())` , but it will add performance penalty for sublisting list. It is better to use traditional for loop in this case.

//Calculate size first to avoid performance penalty calculating in loop each iteration

```
int size = list.size();

for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    String s = list.get(i);
    ...
}
```